# return matching but not exact same strings

Tags: awk, grep

Is there any way to find a word that contains a given string but is not the exact match. For e.g.

```
# cat t.txt
first line
ind is a shortform of india
```

I am trying to return the word "india" because it contains the string "ind" but I do not need the exact match. I have tried this...

```
# grep -o 'ind' t.txt
ind
ind
```

Comment: Maybe `grep -Eo '[A-Za-z]+ind|ind[A-Za-z]+' t.txt`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the expected output. It took me a few reads to understand that the output shown is NOT the expected output but instead some undesirable output. Also add sample input lines like `fooindbar` and `indind` and the associated expected output from those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
grep -Eo '[A-Za-z]+ind|ind[A-Za-z]+' t.txt
```

Output:

```
india
```

The regex `[A-Za-z]+ind|ind[A-Za-z]+` matches `ind` including the preceding or following alphabets.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -Eo '[[:alpha:]]+ind[[:alpha:]]*|[[:alpha:]]*ind[[:alpha:]]+' file
india
fooindbar
```

the above was run on this input file (note the added test case of `ind` appearing in the middle of a string instead of just the start or end):

```
$ cat file
first line
ind is a shortform of india
this fooindbar is the mid-word text
```

You can do the same with GNU awk (for multi-char RS, RT, and `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`) if you prefer:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s+' '/[[:alpha:]]+ind[[:alpha:]]*|[[:alpha:]]*ind[[:alpha:]]+/' file
india
fooindbar
```

or:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:alpha:]]+ind[[:alpha:]]*|[[:alpha:]]*ind[[:alpha:]]+' 'RT{print RT}' file
india
fooindbar
```

Comment: Good answer! What about this one? `awk 'BEGIN{RS=FS=" "}index($1,"ind"){print $1}'`

Comment: @hek2mgl thanks. That wouldn't find `ind` in input like `printf 'foo\tind\n'`or `printf 'foo\nind\n'` since `$1` would be `foo`. You did inspire me to add another possible solution to my answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
first line
ind is a shortform of india
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[[:space:]]+"}match($0,/ind/)&&length>RLENGTH{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
india
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that row separator (`RS`) is one or more whitespaces, this way every word will be treated as row. Then for every row (that is every word) I use [`match`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function which return 1 if found else 0 and set `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` values. If match is found I check if `length` of current row (that is word) is greater than that of match, if it is so I `print` said word. Note that every word is outputted at own line so for example if input file content would be

```
india ind india ind india
```

then output would be

```
india
india
india
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*